# Msg 2760, Level 16, State 1, Line 5 The specified schema name "items" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it

Tags: sql, sql-server, temporal-tables

I am trying to create a temporal table in my SQL Server database. Is anyone familiar with this error in SQL Server:

> Msg 2760, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   The specified schema name "items" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it.

I think there may be something wrong with my user privileges. Any help would be great.

Here's the code:

```
CREATE TABLE [items].[items_Temporal](
    [itemsID] [int] NOT NULL, 
    [item_Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL, 
    [item_Number] [int] NOT NULL, 
    [item_Price] [float] NOT NULL, 
    ValidFrom datetime2(7) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START HIDDEN NOT NULL, 
    ValidTo datetime2(7) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END HIDDEN NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_items_Temporal_items1ID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    (
        [itemsID] ASC
    ), 
    PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME(ValidFrom, ValidTo)
)

WITH(SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = [items].[items_Temporal_History]));
```

Comment: Would help a lot if you included the SQL you're trying to run!

Comment: Maybe you don't have that schema. Try to create it first using `CREATE SCHEMA items`.

Comment: I have a table schema for items with dummy data

Comment: I'm familiar with the error. The text is quite straightforward and lists the two most likely scenarios - there's no `items` schema in your database or there is one but you don't have permissions to use it.

Comment: very clever yeah..

Answer (score 5):

From the answer of Yogesh, you can find whether the schema exists or not.

If the schema `items` not exist, try running

```
CREATE SCHEMA items
```

If you don't have permission to create Schema,

```
USE <database_name>;  
    GRANT CREATE SCHEMA TO <user_name>;  
GO
```

Then create schema and run the code for creating the table.

In the case you have the schema and you are not having the permission to use it,

```
USE <database_name>;  
    GRANT CREATE TABLE TO <user_name>;  
GO
```

Then run the code to create table.

[Read Docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-database-permissions-transact-sql)

Answer (score 1):

Run below query to check actually your are trying to run query in database has item schema in it or not

```
SELECT * FROM sys.schemas WHERE name = 'item'
```

If you have rows in above query then check login user from which you are trying to run this query. Also check does this user has rights to create table by this way you will have idea why this error is coming